# Qt Creator national symbols in Application Output

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8, qt-creator

Windows 10 x64, system display language is English (United States), Russian language pack is also installed.

msvc 2019, clang, Qt Creator 9.0.2 shows Russian symbols in Application Output in an unreadable form. How to fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Çàïîëíåíèå êýøåé'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'cp1251')` returns `Заполнение кэшей`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by set 'Text codec for tools' to 'windows-1251':

[image]